# Can I have a foreign key in my table be null?

Tags: sql-server

I have this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]                  VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [Title]                   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]                 INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TestTopic] FOREIGN KEY ([TopicId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Topic] ([TopicId])
);
```

I would like the allowed values of the TopicId to be null or one that matches the TopicId in the Topic table.

Can someone tell me how I can describe the foreign key for this?

Comment: Have you tried to change `not null` to `null` on the declaration of topicid?

Comment: Just allow `null` to that column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, foreign key constraint columns may allow `NULLs`.  Simply change the foreign key column to allow `NULL` values.  Referential integrity of `NULL` values are not checked.  This is a common practice for optional (zero-or-more) relationships.

Comment: How the reference is possible if foreign key is `NULL`.? A foreign key is a key used to link two tables together. This is sometimes called a referencing key.

Foreign Key is a column or a combination of columns whose values match a Primary Key in a different table.

The relationship between 2 tables matches the Primary Key in one of the tables with a Foreign Key in the second table.

If a table has a primary key defined on any field(s), then you can not have two records having the same value of that field(s).

Comment: A NULL value in a referencing foreign key indicates the referencing table row does not have a corresponding value in the referenced table.  This is an optional (i.e. non-mandatory) relationship.  A non-NULL foreign key value requires a related row in the referenced table.  An OUTER join will be required in cases where the tables are joined on the related key, and all rows from the referencing table are desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. You could do that very easily just by making the field to allow null.. But, keep this in your mind, 'you are breaking data modelling'.

Comment: A foreign key that allows NULLs is not a violation of data modeling best practices, although there are other methods to model an optional relationship.